Is 'at the end of your turn' also 'on your turn'?
Some effects, like a monster's legendary actions, only happen when a turn ends.

Legendary Actions
The phoenix can take 3 legendary actions, choosing from the options below. Only one legendary action can be used at a time and only at the end of another creature's turn. The phoenix regains spent legendary actions at the start of its turn.
Move. The phoenix moves up to its speed.

Other effects, like a rogue's Sneak Attack and a bugbear's Long-Limbed trait, are limited by what turn it currently is.

Sneak Attack
Beginning at 1st level, you know how to strike subtly and exploit a foe's distraction. Once per turn, you can deal an extra 1d6 damage to one creature you hit with an attack if you have advantage on the attack roll. The attack must use a finesse or a ranged weapon.


Long-Limbed. When you make a melee attack on your turn, your reach for it is 5 feet greater than normal.

Say:

On his turn, a rogue attacks the phoenix and deals extra damage with Sneak Attack.
At the end of the rogue's turn, the phoenix uses a legendary action to move away.
This movement provokes an opportunity attack from the rogue.

Is the rogue able to deal extra Sneak Attack damage again? Or unable, because it's still his turn?
If it's a bugbear rogue, would the phoenix avoid provoking an opportunity attack if it remained within the bugbear's long-limbed reach? (On later turns, the phoenix is then free to move away further without provoking any opportunity attacks, as it's already outside the bugbear's now-shortened reach.)

I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it’s been asked before.

The end of your turn is still your turn
This might've been harder to parse if the phrasing were "when another creature's turn ends," but fortunately that's not how the rules for legendary actions are phrased. It's specifically "at the end of another creature's turn."
The Player's Handbook doesn't go into a lot of detail about the edge cases of turns:

During a round, each participant in a battle takes a turn. The order of turns is determined at the beginning of a combat encounter, when everyone rolls initiative. Once everyone has taken a turn, the fight continues to the next round if neither side has defeated the other.

So the rules of the natural English language are all that need to apply here. 'At the end of the day' is still that same day, 'at the end of the episode' is still that same episode of television, 'at the end of the previous century' is still that same century, so 'at the end of the rogue's turn' is still the rogue's turn.
The rogue can't deal extra damage with Sneak Attack again, and a bugbear still has a long-limbed reach at the moment the phoenix moves away.
